# RESTful URLs for two login forms

Tags: acl, restful-authentication

If I two different type of accounts for my site (say `user` and `admin`; they are completely different, so an `admin` cannot be a `user` with administrative permissions.), what is the best way to create restful urls for it?

For one, I was just going to create a `SessionsController` with `create,store,destroy`, but with two, I need to create another controller, and I am not liking the naming that I need to create ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no 'best way' to create restful api's. It depends on your design. The fact that users and admins will be mutually exclusive does not prevent you from storing them in 1 datastore or accessing them via 1 api. If your design calls for radically different approaches  in interacting with both entities, you might choose two api's. If an admin is just another type of user, a single api might be a better choice. Ultimately, the choice is yours.

Comment: Yes, they are two completely separate entities, and the interaction between the two is very minimal. So I guess two different API's is a better choice.